# Could not load dynamic library 'libcusparse.so.11'; dlerror: /usr/local/cuda-11.0/lib64/libcusparse.so.11: file too short; LD_LIBRARY_PATH:

Tags: python, tensorflow

I intalled on my pc tensorflow 2.4.1 and try to test it. I found some simple script at  github that train model on mnist:

```
'''Trains a simple convnet on the MNIST dataset.
Gets to 99.25% test accuracy after 12 epochs
(there is still a lot of margin for parameter tuning).
16 seconds per epoch on a GRID K520 GPU.
'''

from __future__ import print_function
import tensorflow
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K

batch_size = 128
num_classes = 10
epochs = 12

# input image dimensions
img_rows, img_cols = 28, 28

# the data, shuffled and split between train and test sets
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols)
    x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols)
    input_shape = (1, img_rows, img_cols)
else:
    x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)
    x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)
    input_shape = (img_rows, img_cols, 1)

x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
x_train /= 255
x_test /= 255
print('x_train shape:', x_train.shape)
print(x_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
print(x_test.shape[0], 'test samples')

# convert class vectors to binary class matrices
y_train = tensorflow.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = tensorflow.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss=tensorflow.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=tensorflow.keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print('Test loss:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
```

Script works,but does not achieve specified accuracy of 99.25%, and there is some issues. The output is the next:

```
2021-02-09 13:14:27.697775: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.11.0
x_train shape: (60000, 28, 28, 1)
60000 train samples
10000 test samples
2021-02-09 13:14:28.833228: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_cpu_device.cc:41] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
2021-02-09 13:14:28.833686: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
2021-02-09 13:14:28.860694: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:941] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-02-09 13:14:28.861019: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce RTX 3070 computeCapability: 8.6
coreClock: 1.77GHz coreCount: 46 deviceMemorySize: 7.79GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 417.29GiB/s
2021-02-09 13:14:28.861035: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.11.0
2021-02-09 13:14:28.862265: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.11
2021-02-09 13:14:28.862292: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublasLt.so.11
2021-02-09 13:14:28.862870: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
2021-02-09 13:14:28.862986: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
2021-02-09 13:14:28.864383: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
2021-02-09 13:14:28.864417: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'libcusparse.so.11'; dlerror: /usr/local/cuda-11.0/lib64/libcusparse.so.11: file too short; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/cuda-11.0/lib64
2021-02-09 13:14:28.864476: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.8
2021-02-09 13:14:28.864484: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1757] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
2021-02-09 13:14:28.864653: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2021-02-09 13:14:28.865004: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_gpu_device.cc:99] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
2021-02-09 13:14:28.865020: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1261] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2021-02-09 13:14:28.865026: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1267]      
2021-02-09 13:14:28.984319: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:116] None of the MLIR optimization passes are enabled (registered 2)
2021-02-09 13:14:28.984924: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:112] CPU Frequency: 2899885000 Hz
Epoch 1/12
469/469 [==============================] - 22s 46ms/step - loss: 2.2985 - accuracy: 0.1157 - val_loss: 2.2555 - val_accuracy: 0.2294
Epoch 2/12
469/469 [==============================] - 21s 46ms/step - loss: 2.2477 - accuracy: 0.2090 - val_loss: 2.1945 - val_accuracy: 0.3538
Epoch 3/12
469/469 [==============================] - 22s 46ms/step - loss: 2.1888 - accuracy: 0.3076 - val_loss: 2.1107 - val_accuracy: 0.4475
Epoch 4/12
469/469 [==============================] - 22s 46ms/step - loss: 2.1076 - accuracy: 0.3839 - val_loss: 1.9968 - val_accuracy: 0.5344
Epoch 5/12
469/469 [==============================] - 21s 46ms/step - loss: 1.9966 - accuracy: 0.4540 - val_loss: 1.8466 - val_accuracy: 0.6096
Epoch 6/12
469/469 [==============================] - 22s 47ms/step - loss: 1.8526 - accuracy: 0.5101 - val_loss: 1.6598 - val_accuracy: 0.6830
Epoch 7/12
469/469 [==============================] - 22s 47ms/step - loss: 1.6882 - accuracy: 0.5572 - val_loss: 1.4507 - val_accuracy: 0.7304
Epoch 8/12
469/469 [==============================] - 22s 47ms/step - loss: 1.5123 - accuracy: 0.5991 - val_loss: 1.2509 - val_accuracy: 0.7636
Epoch 9/12
469/469 [==============================] - 22s 47ms/step - loss: 1.3526 - accuracy: 0.6302 - val_loss: 1.0789 - val_accuracy: 0.7893
Epoch 10/12
469/469 [==============================] - 22s 48ms/step - loss: 1.2158 - accuracy: 0.6566 - val_loss: 0.9410 - val_accuracy: 0.8085
Epoch 11/12
469/469 [==============================] - 22s 46ms/step - loss: 1.1047 - accuracy: 0.6798 - val_loss: 0.8354 - val_accuracy: 0.8250
Epoch 12/12
469/469 [==============================] - 21s 45ms/step - loss: 1.0291 - accuracy: 0.6960 - val_loss: 0.7543 - val_accuracy: 0.8331
Test loss: 0.7542847394943237
Test accuracy: 0.8331000208854675
```

I'm confused with this issue:

- Could not load dynamic library 'libcusparse.so.11'; dlerror: /usr/local/cuda-11.0/lib64/libcusparse.so.11: file too short; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/cuda-11.0/lib64

It is very strange, I checked the file libcusparse.so.11 and it exist in the same path as other libraries:libcudart.so.11.0, libcublas.so.11, libcublasLt.so.11, libcufft.so.10, libcurand.so.10, libcusolver.so.10,  libcudnn.so.8

Environment:

- OS: Ubuntu 18.04
- GPU Geforce RTX 3070
- Driver version 460.39
- Cuda Toolkit V11.0.194
- Cudnn V8.0.5.39
- Python V3.6.9

Any thoughts?

Comment: "File is too short" sounds like the binary was corrupt or perhaps for the wrong architecture. This is arguably too broad; try to ask one question at a time.

Comment: Updated the question

Answer (score 0):

I had also an issue `Could not load dynamic library 'libcusolver.so.11';`

I just installed Tensorflow==2.4.